# Comparing 2 mixture models using mixtools

Tags: r, distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model, bimodal

I have 2 mixture models I'd like to compare. Specifically, I want to compare lamda (i.e. proportion/area under each distribution) as it looks like there are differences there. Is this possible?

```
dat1_mixmdl <- normalmixEM(dat1, maxit = 2000) 
dat2_mixmdl <- normalmixEM(dat2, maxit = 2000)
```

Which gives me 2 models

```
> summary(dat1)
summary of normalmixEM object:
         comp 1   comp 2
lambda 0.332776 0.667224
mu     0.912283 1.100794
sigma  0.215840 0.154482
loglik at estimate:  259.6641
```

*Note the components are reversed in second data set

```
> summary(dat2)
summary of normalmixEM object:
         comp 1   comp 2
lambda 0.815070 0.184930
mu     1.072223 0.881585
sigma  0.167839 0.225722
loglik at estimate:  202.5543
```

Plot:
[image]

Comment: Lambda is the variable that the package uses to refer to the mixture weight. As the components in the two models are slightly differently parameterized a direct comparison of the mixture weights doesn't make much sense. What do you hope do gain from this?

Comment: Well, dat 1 is before and after a treatment of cells ... i just want to know if the distributions have shifted in some way

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use mixture models for this? I think you could apply a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test for this, although I'm not too familiar with the matter so I may be wrong about that.